# Bad disparity map

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, stereoscopy

I am unable to establish a good disparity map, though I have tuned every of parameters of the SGBM algorithm.

Changing the length of the baseline does not help either. I do understand, that problems are most likely due to the camera setup. Because, I had tried same algo and same tuner with stereo images from internet, and it was working good.

I think these images are a just a little off the epipolar line and so the centers of the cameras, but it is too small. Or even small incline from a an epipolar line can result in such a mess on disparity image?

[SGBM Tuner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZUS4.png)

[Rectified images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkEYp.png)

Comment: Your stereo images are not correctly rectified (left and right images should be the most possibly vertically aligned). See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150354/image-processing-bad-quality-of-disparity-image-with-opencv).

Comment: You can look at this function to stereo rectify your images: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify

Comment: @Catree, I have added rectification in the code, thank you, I have some improvements now, though the depth image is not correct 100%, it does misalign some things. For example, I have attached rectified images to original post, now the algorithm defines person's head closer, than the monitors, that are in the front. I see, that cameras does not perfectly vertically align on the images, this is due to the real camera setup, I suppose(I made a quick baseline and cameras are staggering a little bit). You think it is the main problem and I should setup more robust cameras setup in real world?

Comment: Yes, the stereo images in input of the stereo matching method must be vertically aligned to have good results. See for [instance](https://www.flir.com/iis/machine-vision/stereo-vision) how commercial stereo cameras are setup. Have a look [here](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/v2.29.0/doc/depth-from-stereo.md) to have an overview of how stereo matching algorithms work.

Comment: @Catree, cheers! I will come back after getting a really good vertiaclly-aligned baseline.